# Xcode - set folder reference path via script or plist

Tags: xcode

I've got a folder reference in Xcode that needs to be configurable by the user. I'd prefer to use a script or plist to set its **Location** and **Full Path** properties at build time. I've looked around the web but can't seem to find a way of doing this - is there?

Comment: Can't you just make use of 'Preprocessor Macros'. Just suggesting..

Comment: @JitendraGandhi hrm, possibly, but I would prefer to have the configuration outside of Xcode and outside the project so that I can commit to git without overwriting user settings.